# This modelbinding from jquery, what's wrong with it?

Tags: c#, .net, jquery, asp.net-mvc-2, model-binding

I have the following action:

```
public JsonResult GetGridCell(double longitude, double latitude)
{
    var cell = new GridCellViewModel { X = (int)Math.Round(longitude.Value, 0), Y = (int)Math.Round(latitude.Value, 0) };
    return Json(cell);             
}
```

I'm calling it with the following jquery:

```
$.post('Grid/GetGridCell', { longitude: location.longitude, latitude: location.latitude },
    function (data) {
        InsertGridCellInfo(data);
    });
```

The parameters in my GetGridCell action are never filled (they are null).
When debugging I can see that my Request.Form[0] is called longitude and has the correct value. Same goes for latitude.

When I use the exact same code, but with a `$.get` everything works fine.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Not too sure what you are doing wrong... Have you any route entry for 'Grid/GetGridCell'?

Try decorating your JsonResult method with the AcceptVerbs attribute, creating a separate one method for Get and another for Post

Under a quick test (for me) without any route entry I was able to pass the values:

Using the following for example to post the values:

```
$.post('Home/GetGridCell', { longitude: 11.6, latitude: 22.2 },
function(data) {
    alert(data);
});
```

using $.get intead calls

```
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
    public JsonResult GetGridCell(double longitude, double latitude)
    {
        var cell = new GridCellViewModel { X = (int)Math.Round(longitude), Y = (int)Math.Round(latitude) };
        return Json(cell);
    }
```

and

$.post calls

```
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public JsonResult GetGridCell(double longitude, double latitude, FormCollection collection)
    {
        var cell = new GridCellViewModel { X = (int)Math.Round(longitude), Y = (int)Math.Round(latitude) };
        return Json(cell);
    }
```

Comment: My routing looks fine since I'm hitting the breakpoint in my action.
I tried adding the HttpVerbs.Post attr and FormCollection par, but nothing. The formCollection does contain two keys with names exactly like the parameters and they contain the correct value..
I also pasted your $.post (changed Home to Grid) but still nothing
Bizare

Comment: I think I've found the problem. When I don't use any decimal separators in the parameter I send from jquery, it works fine.
I think it's the region settings that is the problem. I dev on my nl-BE machine where the decimal separator is a colon where jquery gives me a dot.